# 64 bit system struct size

Tags: c, struct, 64-bit

i have the following struct:

```
struct test                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                               
  long long a;                                                                                                                
  int b;                                                                                                                         
};
```

why in 64 bit system the sizeof test will be 16 and not 12?

Comment: Ever heard of alignment?

Comment: even with attribute packed it would still be 16 because long long is 8 bytes and so is int on 64 bit systems, alignment would only make 32 bit systems align to 16 instead of 12

Comment: @technosaurus: Nothing in the C spec requires an int to be 8 bytes long on 64 bit systems. I agree though that most compilers find it easier to implement ints that way.

Comment: yes, it depends on the system, for example: on amd64 int is 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

Your struct needs to be 8 byte aligned because the member `a` needs to be 8 byte aligned (this is on your system, other systems might have different alignment requirements and sizes of `int` and `long long`). This includes every member of an array of your structs. So to ensure the proper alignment of array elements of your struct the size is padded to give an 8 byte alignment.

The standard compliant answer is: "because the compiler can". The answer above is "this is probably what happens and why".

Answer (score -2):

On 64-bit systems, memory is always allocated in chunks of 8 bytes for better (easier) memory management. The strictly minimum size for 1 `int` and one `long long` is 12, but as the nearest multiple of 8 on higher side is 16 so this figure is used. 4 extra bytes are also allocated; this won't kill your system but makes memory management much easier. Try adding a `char`, or even 2 chars, in your `struct`. The size will still remain 16 bytes.

This is because data buses are also 64-bit wide on 64-bit machines and thus transferring a chunk of 8 bytes is required to fill the cache memory efficiently. Individual memory location can still be accessed (of course), its only allocations and transfers which must be performed in larger chunks. If, in your case, 14 bytes were allocated, then whenever system would try to fetch the struct, 4 extra bytes will be fetched. Why? because all transfers are always 64-bits (8 bytes) due to system's data bus size. To fetch 12 bytes, 4 transfers will be used, which will actually bring 16 bytes. These extra bytes, if left unhandled, can cause memory problems. Imagine having an array of your structs, the extra bytes fetched and their management.

As these bytes are going to be fetched anyway due to system design, simplest solution to avoid such problems is to always allocate chunks of 8 bytes (64-bits) which is exactly the case you have observed.

Comment: There are 64 bit cpus with 32 bit data bus width. Memory fetches are done in full cache lines anyway which generally ends up somewhere around 32-128 bytes. Memory will be allocated in units of the largest possible alignment requirement of the data that will be accessed in that memory. For malloc this might end up being 16 bytes (on x86 CPUs because of SSE instructions) or just one byte for stack allocations of char arrays.